# INSERT unique value to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to insert a unique value into my table, however I need to know the `ID` before I create it. I know an `AUTO_INCREMENT` would have solved this problem, but this field is not `AUTO_INCREMENTed`.

This is my code...

```
INSERT INTO networks 
    (NETWORK_ID, ADMIN_USER_ID, NETWORK_NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES 
    ((SELECT MAX(NETWORK_ID)+1 FROM networks) , 3, 'Arcafe', 'habarzel 2 TA')
```

When I run it, I get a warning that I can't use the table in the `FROM`, I guess because it is pointing to itself. How can I achieve what I need? Can I change a field into an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field?

Comment: This link will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467581/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql

Comment: Why do you not want to use auto_increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you set the field to be an auto increment field when it is defined. To do so afterwards, you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE networks MODIFY NETWORK_ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;
```

To then insert an ew record and for it to automatically get an assigned ID, merely omit the field from the insert, eg.

```
INSERT INTO networks 
    (ADMIN_USER_ID, NETWORK_NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES 
    (3, 'Arcafe', 'habarzel 2 TA')
```

Comment: Thanks for the ALTER advice for the AUTO_INCREMENT. 
I am looking for a solution for the INSERTion of a unique ID.

Comment: I went ahead and used the ALTER, proves to be the best idea. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate table for generation unique ids and use this ids

Comment: MySQL has auto_increment for this purpose, a separate table is unnecessary and error prone.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I thought I could use a seperate table that IS auto_incremented, and use that number. It would require an extra SELECT though. I am trying to stick to pure php/mysql as it is right now though.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE networks CHANGE NETWORK_ID NETWORK_ID int auto_increment
```

[Alter Table Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks for the ALTER advice for the AUTO_INCREMENT. 
I am looking for a solution for the INSERTion of a unique ID.