# Creating key values mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database, primary-key

I have worked with databases before where the key attributes for entities looked like

83NG92R8B202NG

I am trying to build a db myself and was wondering if there was a sql command that automatically assigned a key to an added tuple or I had to create some sort of random attribute algorithm myself.

Comment: Are you referring to a uniqueidentifier datatype? If so it is only hex digits...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a UUID? More information in mysql docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

If that doesn't fit your needs, take a look at this topic:

[Generating a random & unique 8 character string using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql)