# Save 20 random character in mysql

Tags: mysql, random

I want save randomly generated 20 character's alpha-numeric in mysql.
What type of fields is better choice?
varchar, binarym

Comment: If you want alpha-numeric values, store them as strings.  If they are always 20 characters, use `char(20)`; otherwise `varchar(20)`.

Comment: Google: *mysql generate random string*

Answer (score 0):

The best would be `CHAR(20)`. 
But if you need to choose between `varcher` or `binary`, choose `VARCHAR(20)`.

Here is a discussion how to generate a random string using SQL in case you want the generation to happen in `MySQL`: [Generating a random & unique 8 character string using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql)