# What's the simplest way to generate a unique string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want a column in my table to generate a unique, collision free string without having to re-check the table. What's the easiest way to do this? It does not need to be random, however I would prefer not to just stringify the primary key.

Comment: [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257391/how-do-i-generate-a-unique-random-string-for-one-of-my-mysql-table-columns/39259742