# MySQL - inserting 70000 random unique strings efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm working on a project, in which I should generate at least 70000 codes which contain 8 alphanumeric characters. The codes must be unique. currently I am using php to generate these codes with the following function :

```
function random_unique_serial($length, PDO $conn) {
    $codeCheck=FALSE;
    while (!$codeCheck) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomCode = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomCode .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code=:code";
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindvalue(":code", $randomCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        $count = $st->rowcount();
        if ($count==0) {
            $codeCheck=TRUE;
        } else {
            $codeCheck=FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $randomCode;
}
```

As you see this codes checks the database for every single code generated to make sure it is not a duplicate. This should work theoretically. However this is very slow and causes the request to time out. I tried increasing execution time but that also didn't help.

Then I decided to use a database side approach and used this solution :
[Generating a random & unique 8 character string using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql)

This is also very slow and some of the generated codes are less than 8 characters long.

could you please suggest a better solution?

Comment: use UNIQUE index.

Comment: in this case the code crashes and code generation stops.

Comment: If your code crashed because a (valid) constraint fails, then maybe fix your code.

Comment: use [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to silently discard code crashes, with UNIQUE index

Comment: That will depend on PDO error mode and how you handle it. If you set for exception, if not caught it will halt the script.

Comment: And is it `rowcount`or `rowCount`? `bindvalue`or `bindValue`?

Comment: Is your database empty at the moment you insert the codes? If so - you can check if the codes are unique BEFORE making any inserts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t (code CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Define a PHP function to generate a random string:

```
function random_string(integer $length = 8): string {
    return bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(ceil($length/2), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
}
```

Use PHP to build a multi-value INSERT statement, ram that into the database, count how many were inserted, and repeat until the required number are inserted:

```
function insert_records(\PDO $pdo, integer $need = 70000): void {
    $have = 0;
    while ($have < $need) {
        // generate multi value INSERT
        $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO t VALUES ';
        for ($i = 1; $i < $need; $i++) {
            $sql .= sprintf('("%s"),', random_string());
        }
        $sql .= sprintf('("%s");', random_string());

        // pass to database and ask how many records were inserted
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        $count  = $result->rowCount();

        // adjust bookkeeping values so we know how many we have and how many
        // we need
        $need -= $count;
        $have += $count;
    }
}
```

On my machine (Amazon Linux c2.small), the run time for 70k records is about 2 seconds:

```
real    0m2.136s
user    0m1.256s
sys     0m0.212s
```

The relevant tricks in this code, to make it fast, are:

- Sending the minimum number of SQL statements necessary to generate the needed number of records. Using a multi-value insert - `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (), (), ... ();` - really helps this as it minimizes the total amount of statement processing MySQL has to do *and* it tells us how many records were inserted without having to do another query.
- Using `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid having to check for the existence of every single code we insert, which is really really expensive.
- Using the fastest possible string generating function we can for our needs. In my experience, `mcrypt_create_iv` is a fast generator that is cryptographically secure, so it provides an ideal balance of security and performance.
- Using the ASCII character set and fixed width `CHAR` to remove unnecessary byte overhead and `UNIQUE` to enforce de-duplication.

Comment: This was the smartest way of doing it. I added even more columns to the query and it was done in a few seconds. Great!

Comment: That's a nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that with mysql alone, a stored procedure will help - you can still create and call that with php. The stored procedure uses the substring of a md5 hash, created from rand(). The column where the string is to be inserted needs to be `unique`. Replace table name and column in in this part:

```
insert ignore into foo (`uniqueString`)
```

---

```
delimiter //
create procedure createRandomString (in num int)
  begin
    declare i int default 0;
    while i < num do
      insert ignore into foo (`uniqueString`) values (substr(md5(rand()), 1, 8));
      set i = i + 1;
    end while;
  end //
delimiter ;

call createRandomString (70000);
```

I did a quick test, I got 69934 random unique strings inserted on a remote db (from the 70000 runs) within 10s 603ms. Running the same procedure with 80000 as parameter

```
call createRandomString(80000);
```

runs 12s 434ms for me, inserting 77354 rows - so you have at least 70000 in little time.

Will produce results like this:

[image]

---

If you want to make sure to have exactly the number of rows inserted as called, use this (but note to set the max_sp_recursion_depth to what it was before after calling the procedure, default is 0):

```
delimiter //
create procedure createRandomString2 (in num int)
  begin
    declare i int default 0;
    while i < num do
      insert ignore into foo (uniqueString) values (substr(md5(rand()), 1, 8));
      set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    if (select count(id) from foo) < num then
      call createRandomString2(num - (select count(id) from foo));
   END IF;
  end //
delimiter ;

set max_sp_recursion_depth = 100; 
call createRandomString7 (70000);
set max_sp_recursion_depth = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

Here I'm inserting (approx.) 16, unique, 3-character (0-9/a-z) strings...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (my_string CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table 
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ,SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ,SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ) x;


//Repeat this block as necessary

INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table 
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ,SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ,SUBSTR('0123456789abcdefghihjlmnopqrstuvwxyz',(RAND()*35)+1,1)
             ) x
          FROM my_table;

//End of block


SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----------+
| my_string |
+-----------+
| 0he       |
| 112       |
| 24c       |
| 322       |
| 4b7       |
| 7vq       |
| as7       |
| g7n       |
| h66       |
| i54       |
| idd       |
| m62       |
| mqt       |
| obh       |
| x75       |
| xz4       |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Eight digit numbers are guaranteed unique: 00000000, 00000001, 00000002, ...  If you don't want the codes so obvious, then select eight different sets of ten alphanumeric characters to replace the ten digits in a given position.  There will still be a pattern, but it will be less obvious: ql4id78sk, ql4id78s3, ql4id78sa, ...

Beyond that, you could encrypt the original numbers, and the encryptions are guaranteed unique.  A 32 bit block cypher will produce four byte results, giving eight hex characters.