# Huge MySQL Random Alphanumeric String

Tags: mysql, database, uuid, google-cloud-sql

I wish to let database column to auto generate around 300++ random alphanumeric string every time I insert a new entry to the database. The code below only capable of size of 36.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER testdata
BEFORE INSERT ON testdata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.token IS NULL THEN
    SET new.token = uuid();
  END IF;
END
;;
```

Thanks for everyone that answer this question.

Comment: What's the purpose of this string? There's techniques [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql) to generate alphanumeric sequences, but if you need something cryptographically unique and unguessable, `RAND()` is too predictable for that.

Comment: Hi. @tadman Thanks for your reply. The purpose of this string is like some kind of authentication. Mind suggest any better method for me to apply on which is crytographically unique?

Comment: UUID-type values are only really intended to be unique, not unpredictable. For something cryptographically unique you'll need a secure random number generator and then encode it in base-62 or something of that sort. This may not be the best thing for MySQL to be handling, but you can try. It's a lot easier to do in an external programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just chain together the output of multiple calls to `uuid()`, i.e.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER testdata
BEFORE INSERT ON testdata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.token IS NULL THEN
        SET new.token = CONCAT(REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), ...)
    END IF;
END
;;
```

Note here that I remove the hyphen from the UUIDs because they are superfluous and do not do much in the way of making the strings more random.

Comment: Hi. @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your answer. It is working like the way I wish for.