# How can I create a unique random 8 character id with mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to generate a random id for each entry in mysql but I don't want to use auto increment for security reasons. How can I create default value for the id column that creates a unique random string of 8 characters to use as the id for each user?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738409/5513005) might help you.

Comment: What is a "character"?  Just letters and digits?  All 256?  Base64?  Consider `LEFT(TO_BASE64(UNHEX(MD5(UUID()))), 8)` (64 diff chars; needs 5.6.1) or `LEFT(MD5(UUID()), 8)` (just hex)