# How can you generate a fixed number of rows in MySQL v8 for performance testing?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to create performance tests in MySQL v8. For this, I need to generate a fixed number of rows, so I can insert them into my tables.

In PostgreSQL, I would do something like:

```
insert into film(title)
select random_string(30)
from   generate_series(1, 100000);
```

Here, `random_string(int)` is a custom function. In MySQL, I could use something as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884557/9740433, which would be sufficient I suppose.

How do I generate the 100k rows in MySQL v8?

Comment: you can create a procedure where you can iterate data using while and insert that data into temporary table .after that you can access that temporary table for your testing purpose.

Comment: You're using 8, so it's easy. The manual even provides an example just like this

Comment: It's a common table expression

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, as per comment by Strawberry:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

You might want to alter the recursion depth: `SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = 1000000;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old-fashioned `cross join` method:

```
with d as (
      select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
             select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
             select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
     ),
     n as (
      select (1 + d1 + d2 * 10 + d3 * 100 + d4 * 1000 + d5 * 10000) as n
      from d d1 cross join
           d d2 cross join
           d d3 cross join
           d d4 cross join
           d d5
     )
select *
from n;
```

It would be interesting to test the performance of the `cross join` against the recursive CTE.