# How to randomly generate numbers and letters in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have created a table that stores numberplates in SQL.
The table looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE tblCar
    (
    VehicleRegNo VARCHAR(10)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK(VehicleRegNo>0),
    Make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    EngineSize VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DateRegistered DATE NOT NULL,
RentalPerDay MONEY NOT NULL,
Available CHAR(1)NOT NULL
);
```

I also have used a statement that is:

```
SELECT LEFT(NEWID(),8)
```

I can generate random numbers and letters with this statement but I am unsure of how to 
insert it into my table.Should I declare a variable or is this a suitable way.
The VehicleRegNo column will store the numberplates.

Comment: At what point do you want to insert this value into table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a random & unique 8 character string using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql)

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal-I wish to insert the data at the first record that is being displayed and i want it to be shown for the next 15