# Best URL ID implementation

Tags: php

I'm trying to come up with a good way to avoid directly using ID's in URL's to look up table entries.  The main reason is that for privacy reasons, I don't want my users to be able to simply change, say, /?unique_id=10 to /?unique_id=11 and see someone else's information.

I've noticed many sites use randomly generated strings, but what's the best structural implementation of something like this?

Thanks!

Oh, and I doubt it matters, but I'm using PHP.

EDIT:
The information contained on the pages is public information. That is, anyone with the link should be able to access the page without trouble. What I want to prevent is people simply iterating through IDs and seeing everything in the database. I prefer that only people that have been given a link access the page. That said, it's not a huge problem if a random person stumbles across it.

Also, I don't want people looking at the ID to figure out how many total entries there are.

Comment: How sensitive is the information you're displaying?

Comment: Any `guid` / `uuid` method would work, but you shouldn't rely on obscurity of ID for security...

Comment: Are you trying to limit access to a user's own information?  If so, might I suggest you use session variables based on the user's login info?

Comment: I should have been more clear:  The information contained on the pages is public information.  That is, anyone with the link should be able to access the page without trouble.  What I want to prevent is people simply iterating through IDs and seeing everything in the database.  I prefer that only people that have been given a link access the page.  That said, it's not a huge problem if a random person stumbles across it.

Comment: Oh, and another thing I don't want is for people to know how many entries are in the database.  Using IDs, all they have to do is find the point at which the ID leads to a "Not valid" page, and they know exactly how many entries there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need some kind of user check to make sure people arent seeing other peoples records anyway, but using a GUID for this is a good start.

You could use a hash of something like record1, record2 etc, but a determinted hacker could easily do this.

Another option is to use record aliases so each record has a string that represents it which you then use as the key.  You often see this in wordpress or other CMS systems.

So if your id refers to a post maybe take the title and replace spaces with -

eg.  www.example.com/article.php?id=Summer-is-the-best-time-of-year

Comment: I think the string solution is the best.  Say I just wanted to use a random string of characters though, instead of an actual title.  What's the best way to make that string unique in order to avoid collisions?

Comment: a GUID! otherwise you need to use a autoincrement field combined with somthing else and turned into letters like say 123-GHF the person can guess the 123 bit but not the letters.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't had to deal with that at url level. You just take care of that at the session so if user 123 tries to access yoursite.com/unique_id=456 the session checking will prevent him from doing it. I mean you're talking about private pages isn't it ?

Even if you encode it (the user id) it will be accessible as a hash or something which would be nothing more than obfuscation which is not as good as preventing access on your own (with a session)

Answer (score 1):

I have used MySQL's [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function for this, but you should definitely use permission checking to ensure that users aren't able to view data for other users.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467611/224684) shows simply how to create a unique identifer.

Comment: This is actually perfect for what I'm trying to do.  I had no idea that function existed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can encrypt them use md5(id) and search for the record the has the same md5(id)
ie

```
select * from table where md5(id) = '$encrypted'
```

Comment: That has to do a full table scan and calculate and md5 for every row in your table.  If you have more than a few rows, performance will compare pretty poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use AJAX calls for any queries to the DB rather than including them in the URL $_GET.

Comment: How would this improve security? The ID is still visible to the client, no matter whether Ajax is used for the request or not.

Comment: AJAX requests are not visible to the client and are not encoded in the URL like variables being passed via $_GET