# MySQL Database ID's

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I'm creating a website that will be updated with contributor posts, comments, etc, etc and I'm wondering the best way of creating the id's to prevent there ever being a duplicate in ANY of the tables.  I'm using a timestamp at the moment along with a unique number at the end, like:

```
$time = time();
$id= time().'-'.mt_rand(1000, 9999);
```

To Output:

> 1378291391-1167, 1378294733-8990, 1378294934-3336, etc, etc, etc.

Can anyone see a problem with this type of id creation system?

Comment: Yes, random numbers aren't guaranteed unique

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - please explain why you need the ids to be unique over multiple tables and we'll tell you why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Why does the id have to be globally unique? `foo.id`, `bar.id`, etc... ARE globally unique, even if the id portion can be duplicated in multiple tables.

Comment: I'd just like to keep the id's the same length really as they are the user id's needed for each profile page identification. There's no real need for them to be unique over multiple tables, just to be a consistent format I guess

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker but am I right in thinking that it would be Extremely unlikely for there to ever be 2 ID's the same using this system?

Comment: Unlikely, but not impossible (about 8999:1) for requests made in the same second - autoincrement is guaranteed as long as you take a couple of precautions... you control the db, so you can set autoincrement steps to ensure no clashes across your tables; or use table prefix values

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker I guess in many ways there's no real guarantee with any system that doesn't use extensive precautions. I think I'll stick with the system I have and increase the value of the rand() to make a string of 9 numbers to be safe

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467581/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would increase uniqueness by using

- `microtime`() instead of `time()`
- if strings are allowed, appending microtime with `uniqid()` function
- and using mt_rand with larger values (`mt_rand(0, 10000000)`)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

https://www.php.net/microtime

Comment: That's `uniqid` and not `uniqueid`, which I believe is what you meant. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php - which I noticed on the same page. I believe that was an error from the person who posted it on PHP.net

Answer (score -1):

Use autoincrement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     col1 CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html