# Generate a random and unique ID in a column when an entry is created

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make it so when an entry is created in a table, one of the columns `unique_id` automatically gets filled with a randomly generated integer? Can this be done straight from mysql? I've seen that you can automatically fill it with a timestamp and such, so is it possible to automatically fill it with a randomly generated integer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467581/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

IF you need a unique number for id purpose. you may make your column auto-incremented. Remember this that if you are going with this you need to make it either unique or primary key. I think this is the easiest way. You will get a contiguous increment.

Comment: auto-increment will create unique number-`correct` but OP need Random unique number

Comment: Yes that is why I mentioned here it will be contiguous incremented number.

Answer (score 0):

`you can try this`

```
SELECT FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999) AS my_random_number
FROM mytable
WHERE "my_random_number" NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable)
LIMIT 1
```

OR SImply this `SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000);`

Comment: won't I have to do this everytime? or running this query in sql will make it so the column will automatically generate a random number everytime an entry is created?

Comment: you could make a link like you need with this

Comment: so I can't use something like this

`ALTER TABLE files
ALTER random_id SET DEFAULT FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000)`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work, how can I set the DEFAULT value of random_id column to a function that creates a `unique` random number

Comment: i have no idea about `php` you asked for `mysql cmd` i gave it

Answer (score 0):

use RAND() and concat date and time with it so you can have a unique number..

Answer (score 0):

Use UUID function,A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid