# Group array and assign unique number by same key value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an an array in which I need to assign unique batch id to products belongs to different Retailer

```
foreach($data as $type){
$grouped_types[$type['retailer']][] = $type;
}
```

$data is my array

```
Array
 ( 
[1] => Array
    (

        [productid] => 1001
        [mrp] => 444
        [whpoid] => 105
        [retailer] => HYD-48AC
        [manufacturerbarcode] => 
        [comments] => 
        [lastmodifiedby] => 
        [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [productid] => 1002
        [mrp] => 444
        [whpoid] => 106
        [retailer] => HYD-48AC
        [manufacturerbarcode] => 
        [comments] => 
        [lastmodifiedby] => 
        [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [productid] => 1003
        [mrp] => 444
        [whpoid] => 105
        [retailer] => HYD-48AC
        [manufacturerbarcode] => 
        [comments] => 
        [lastmodifiedby] => 
        [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    )
 [4] => Array
    (
        [productid] => 1005
        [mrp] => 444
        [whpoid] => 105
        [retailer] => PUN-48AC
        [manufacturerbarcode] => 
        [comments] => 
        [lastmodifiedby] => 
        [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    )
```

Expected Output
So array 2 and 3 belongs to same retailer so they have same batch id.I need to assign unique batch id to each diff retailer but product under same retailer should have same batch id.Kindly help.Thanks in advance

```
Array
 ( 
  [1] => Array
  (

    [productid] => 1001
    [mrp] => 444
    [whpoid] => 105
    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
    [comments] => 
    [lastmodifiedby] => 
    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    [batchid] => B001
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [productid] => 1002
    [mrp] => 444
    [whpoid] => 106
    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
    [comments] => 
    [lastmodifiedby] => 
    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    [batchid] => B002
  )

 [3] => Array
   (
    [productid] => 1003
    [mrp] => 444
    [whpoid] => 105
    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
    [comments] => 
    [lastmodifiedby] => 
    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    [batchid] => B002
   )
  [4] => Array
  (
    [productid] => 1005
    [mrp] => 444
    [whpoid] => 105
    [retailer] => PUN-48AC
    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
    [comments] => 
    [lastmodifiedby] => 
    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
    [batchid] => B003
  )
```

Comment: you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467581/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql

Comment: I have posted your solution please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

Take key value pair of retailer array like example given below

```
//Where key as retailer id and value as batch id
$retailers = array(
     "HYD-48AC" => "B001",
     "PUN-48AC" => "B001",
);
```

Now in you foreach loop apply below logic

```
foreach($data as $type){
    $batch_id = $retailers[$type['retailer'];
    $type['batchid'] = $batch_id;
    $grouped_types[$type['retailer']][] = $type;
}
```

This will 100% work for you.

Comment: Modified a little bit and worked great.Thanks a ton

Comment: Glad to head that.:)

Comment: Hi Ronak
I want to make a new array foreach retailer  in which I want to calculate totaltal payment of each retailer.

Comment: Each above array has individual itemamount and I want to get total sum of itemamount group by retailer
Expected output
$retailers = array(
     "HYD-48AC" => 600,
     "PUN-48AC" => 100,
);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `retailer` as key and append elements to it.

So, there would be 3 elements under `HYD-48AC`

and one element under `PUN-48AC`

```
<?php 
$arr = Array( 
1 => Array
    (

         'productid' => 1001
        , 'mrp' => 444
        , 'whpoid' => 105
        , 'retailer' => 'HYD-48AC'
        , 'manufacturerbarcode' => '' 
        , 'comments' => ''
        , 'lastmodifiedby' => ''
        , 'lastmodifieddate' => '2019-02-12 11:49:19'
    ),
    2 => Array
    (
         'productid' => 1002
        , 'mrp' => 444
        , 'whpoid' => 106
        , 'retailer' => 'HYD-48AC'
        , 'manufacturerbarcode' => '' 
        , 'comments' => ''
        , 'lastmodifiedby' => ''
        , 'lastmodifieddate' => '2019-02-12 11:49:19'
    ),

3 => Array
    (
         'productid' => 1003
        , 'mrp' => 444
        , 'whpoid' => 105
        , 'retailer' => 'HYD-48AC'
        , 'manufacturerbarcode' => '' 
        , 'comments' => ''
        , 'lastmodifiedby' => ''
        , 'lastmodifieddate' => '2019-02-12 11:49:19'
    ),
 4 => Array
    (
         'productid' => 1005
        , 'mrp' => 444
        , 'whpoid' => 105
        , 'retailer' => 'PUN-48AC'
        , 'manufacturerbarcode' => '' 
        , 'comments' => ''
        , 'lastmodifiedby' => ''
        , 'lastmodifieddate' => '2019-02-12 11:49:19'
    )

    );
$groupedArr = [];
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $groupedArr[$elem['retailer']][] = $elem;
 }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($groupedArr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [HYD-48AC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 1001
                    [mrp] => 444
                    [whpoid] => 105
                    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
                    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
                    [comments] => 
                    [lastmodifiedby] => 
                    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 1002
                    [mrp] => 444
                    [whpoid] => 106
                    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
                    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
                    [comments] => 
                    [lastmodifiedby] => 
                    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 1003
                    [mrp] => 444
                    [whpoid] => 105
                    [retailer] => HYD-48AC
                    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
                    [comments] => 
                    [lastmodifiedby] => 
                    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
                )

        )

    [PUN-48AC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 1005
                    [mrp] => 444
                    [whpoid] => 105
                    [retailer] => PUN-48AC
                    [manufacturerbarcode] => 
                    [comments] => 
                    [lastmodifiedby] => 
                    [lastmodifieddate] => 2019-02-12 11:49:19
                )

        )

)
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I have already done it similar way but how to assign batchid.

Comment: Which is the field for batch id?

Comment: I have to insert new key batchid and its value will be unique

Comment: please refer to expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate array of retailer batch id, where retailer group is the `key` and `value` is the batch id and use `array_walk` to iterate through and assign the related retailer batch id to products.

```
$retailers = ['HYD-48AC' => 'B001', 'PUN-48AC' => 'B002'];
array_walk($products, function(&$v, $k) use ($retailers){
  !empty($retailers[$v['retailer']]) ? ($v['batchid'] = $retailers[$v['retailer']]) : '';
});
```