# Custom Unique Id SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, unique

How would I go about seeing if order id is taken and if it is taken then to make another one and see if its unique in the database.

I've got this prototype down however no luck. Doesn't execute if there is nothing in the database.
Also doesn't do anything if order id is not unique.

```php
$order_id = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM `bucks-orders`') as $item){
    if ($item['order-id'] != $order_id){
        $insertOrder = "<sql code here>";

        $conn->query($insertOrder);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to check if isn't in database just use WHERE order-id=$order_id with do while loop for database rows.

Comment: Why not use [RFC 4122 (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier?msclkid=c0b859d1cf0811ecba0f2ec806c0a5ef) which has a one in a billion chance of being duplicated. [See an example](https://3v4l.org/mr0aU)

Otherwise, if you're using numeric values, why not use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your primary key?

Comment: `$conn->query()` returns a [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) or a [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), not an array. You need to call [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to retrieve results.

Comment: @kmoser , $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `bucks-orders`') works and retrieves the results fine.

Comment: @Jaquarh I am already using md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), what I want to find out is how to check if a item with same id already exists and if it exists then repeat until its unique in the database.

Comment: @kmoser I also couldn't understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467581/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql

Comment: `UUID()` ([MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)) will give you e.g. `d392d574-cf0b-11ec-a11b-482ae31302cf`. Whatever you do, you definitely don't want to fetch all your data and check if the ID exists yet. Imagine 1M rows. You could just `SELECT uid FROM whatever WHERE uid = '$uidCandidate` and see if results are returned. If not, use it.  You could just use `hrtime(true)` (17 digit high-resolution time in nanoseconds) and append `mt_rand()`, the chances of collision are nearly non-existent, and you also get chronological IDs.

Comment: If you wanted something shorter and alphanumeric, e.g. `base_convert(hrtime(true) . mt_rand(100000,999999), 10, 36);` would give you `186569463382000480468` as `13dgtn4tqnxw8c` (21 vs. 14 chars). Be aware that maximum integer size in PHP (64-bit) is 9223372036854775807 (or 19 chars), so you can only append so many more digits to `hrtime()` output before you run into trouble if you use it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the DB, try setting the field to 'unique'.

This should do the checking for having one entry matching one id, never duplicating.

It does not sound like you after a mathematically unique number but just a unique id per DB field

Info link:

https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_unique.asp

Comment: What's the difference between "mathematically unique" and "unique in the table"?

Comment: Unique in the table is just any value that doesn't exist already. Could be just "A". But using math would be something like UUID() a long string, unique because the chances of generating two of the same are almost non existent.

Comment: I see, "mathematical" as in "generator/algorithm that yields likely unique values on each iteration". Otherwise, any given value that doesn't recur in a given set is "mathematically unique", including the "A" in [A, B, C].